# How to insert a HTML page into an APEX Region?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have the following HTML page which works perfectly fine as a HTML page; however when I try put it into APEX by entering the code into a Region it just goes all wrong.

When the submit button is pressed, it takes the user to a new page with the IFRAME on rather than just refreshing the page as it does in a HTML page. The other issue is the aesthetics, it looks perfect in Firefox but in IE the IFRAME is half way down the page. When investigating in Firebug I see no attributes which would cause this.

Is there a method of embedding a HTML page into an APEX form page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
</head>

<form action="http://ukserver/orderlist.asp" target="orderResults">
Enter Order Number: <input id="ord" type="text" name="ord" maxlength="50" size="20"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<iframe id="orderResults" name="orderResults" src="blank.html" width="100%" height="50%">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the page in FireFox which as you can see looks ok.
[image]

This is the page in IE which is incorrect
[image]

Update:

The HTML page seems to work perfectly in the HTML header of the APEX page but its above my tabs and region which isnt the place where i want it. I tried to find an order (1112) and it returned the following 'File not found' which is correct.

[image]

Hi Tony, I created another IFRAME and i guess I'm half way there. I now just have to get the HTML form working, please see below:

[image]

Comment: Surely you can't just embed one HTML page inside another, regardless of whether the outer page is APEX or not?  You would need to embed the inner page in a frame?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I assumed if i put the code in a HTML region it would have been all ok?

Comment: No, you will end up with invalid HTML

Comment: @TonyAndrews OK, do you know of any methods in APEX which could search a specific folder for the order number entered into the text box, and return the result as a hyperlink to the invoice (opens as a PDF)? In APEX could a text box and button be used for the search section, and a report to return the results?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a PDF file in a folder on a server somewhere for each order.  If the names of the files are predictable given the order number then you should be able to generate a link something like this:

1) Create an item to accept the order number e.g. P12_ORDER_NUMBER.

2) Create a button to submit the page

3) Create a report that displays when P12_ORDER_NUMBER is not null and selects:

```
select '//server/path/fileprefix' || :P12_ORDER_NUMBER || '.pdf' as url
from dual;
```

4) Convert the report column into a link via the column attributes so that clicking on it launches the file.

Comment: Thats right, Thank you for pointing me down the right path. I've completed the above however within the 'orderlist' folder there are other folders. Is there a way I can search for the number entered in \\ukserver\orderlist in pl/sql?